# Edit exisiting class propertys or make system wide changes to a class

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, ios8, sklabelnode

I have problem with iOS 8 and the SKLabelNode Class.
I used in my Project lot of SKLabelNodes(We speak about 120 nodes) and in iOS8 Apple has changed the built in FontType and now all my Labels hardly readable. I would like to change back, but I dont want to edit all the Nodes by one. I would like to change the SKLabelNode Class Defaults Font type. Is it possible? Or any other solution?

Comment: I hope you have neither created 120 subclasses of SKLabelNode nor written 120 different blocks of code where each creates a new label. Both would be indicators that the real problem is coding style and you would only have yourself to blame. Ideally you have 1 parametrized method that creates labels for you, where you could simply add the line label.fontName = @"Arial" to fix this issue for all labels.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your best bet would be to use a category [Apple Category Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2)

Or take a look at swizzling. There's a good tutorial here [Swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/)

I think your best bet is actually method swizzling to replace the getter or modify the category to add a new init that sets a default font. Hope this helps.

Comment: Overwriting the designated init in a category won't work because you can't call the original init and will end up with a class that is not correctly initialized. If adding a new init would be an option it would probably be easier, and cleaner, to just subclass SKLabelNode and set a font in the overwritten designated initializer. It'll probably come down to method swizzling.